# How to add roles to phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

I'm an administrator of a phabricator installation. How can I add some roles to configure permissions? Such as setting a new user group, en/disabled some buttons/functions etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phabricator doesn't really have roles.  Instead, if you want to group your users, you would group them with a project.  Then you would grant access to areas of the application to that project.  When the employee is re-assigned, add them to the new project.  If they get a promotion (i.e. developer to Sr. developer) they may have new privileges and responsibilities; add them to a 'project' that reflects what they should be allowed to do.

Comment: What does this mean:" This object has a custom policy controlling who can take this action" ? How to do this ? For example : phabricator.kde.org

Comment: Well, there are User, Bot, Administrator and Mailing list roles, but the answer is correct.